# Lisp constants used in multiple places

Tags: constants, lisp

There are some constants in my application that I want to use throughout the program. This is what I currently do:

```
(defconst my-constant-alist
  '((my-foo . "foo")
    (my-bar . "bar")))
```

within the code I then use:

```
(alist-get 'my-foo my-constant-alist)
```

However, since I use the constant in a couple of places, it just does not look good.
What is an elegant way of using constants spread all over the program in lisp?

Comment: Why you don't use `(defconst my-foo "foo")` and `(defconst my-bar "bar")`? This is the most used form of constant definition.

Comment: @Renzo The problem is that I have multiple more constants (currently about 20) and I thought that there must be a better way to handle this.

Comment: Then you could define a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html) so that you can make a multiple set of constant definitions with a single form.

Comment: @Renzo Do you have an example for the current minimalistic use case?

Comment: Lisp is a family of languages; I assume that you are using emacs lisp but you need to add the appropriate language tag. "_What is an elegant way...._", "_...there must be a better way to handle this._" -- What is wrong with using `defconst` (which lets you document each symbol with a docstring in elisp)? Without more information I think the answer is: don't use an alist, just use `defconst`. You need to clarify: what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve. Some actual code illustrating the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a bunch of constants the best approach is usually to have a bunch of constants: you are going to need to wire in the names of things anyway: there's nothing to be gained by `(f '<name>)` or `(m <name>)` instead of just `<name>` unless you want `<name>` to refer to something else as well.  If you want those constants all defined in one place then that's easy.  I assume (based on `defconst`) you are writing elisp, and if so a macro like this will serve:

```
(defmacro define-constants (&rest forms)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (form)
                 `(defconst ,@form))
               forms)))
```

And now

```
(define-constants
  (foo 1)
  (bar 2)
  ...)
```

(Disclaimer: I have not kept up with the changes in elisp in the last 20 years or more: the above works on Emacs 27.2.)

If you're using Common Lisp or some other Lisp there are often better approaches.